# I can't align the Text to the center of the Shape I create

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I insert text into the Shape but I can't center it. i tried to do it I don't understand it at all.

```
private void AddTextAndSetCenter(String file)
        {
            using (var presentation = PresentationDocument.Open(file, true))
            {
                var tree = presentation
                    .PresentationPart
                    .SlideParts
                    .ElementAt(0)
                    .Slide
                    .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeTree>()
                    .First();

                var shape = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape();

                shape.NonVisualShapeProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeProperties();

                shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties
                {
                    Name = "My Shape",
                    Id = (UInt32)tree.ChildElements.Count - 1
                });

                shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties());

                shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties());

                shape.ShapeProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties();

                shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D();

                shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset
                {
                    X = 10000000,
                    Y = 2000000,
                });

                shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents
                {
                    Cx = 1000000,
                    Cy = 1000000,
                });

                shape.ShapeProperties.Append(new PresetGeometry
                {
                    Preset = ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle
                });

                var outline = new A.Outline(new A.SolidFill(new A.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "000000" }));

                outline.Width = (5 * 12700);

                shape.ShapeProperties.Append(outline);

                // Create a TextBody and add a Paragraph with the specified text
                shape.TextBody = new TextBody(new A.BodyProperties(), new A.ListStyle(), new A.Paragraph(new A.Run(new A.Text("Hello"))));


                tree.AppendChild(shape);
            }
        }
```

From the code I put in, I can see that I only do the part of creating the Text into the shape, but I can't center it at all. please help me thank you.